Data filter by from and to date is not coming in firestore flutter
i am filtering data in my flutter app by from and to date, like greater than from from date and less than to date. But it gives data on some date range and does not give on some date range.
Like if i chose dates from 2024-4-8 to 2024-4-18 it does not give data, whereas if i selected from 2024-3-12 to 2023-4-18 it gives data properly..
here is code:
    CollectionReference transactions =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('transaction');
    Query filteredQuery = transactions;



        if (filteringController.selectedFromDate.value != '' &&

          filteringController.selectedToDate.value != '') {

        // Filter by date range
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.where('date',
            isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 
                   filteringController.selectedFromDate.value
            isEqualTo: filteringController.selectedToDate.value);
      }

   
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectFromDate(context),
              child: Text(
                filteringController.selectedFromDate.value != ''
                    ? filteringController.selectedFromDate.value
                    : 'From Date',
              ),                ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => _selectToDate(context),
              child: Text(
                filteringController.selectedToDate.value != ''
                    ? filteringController.selectedToDate.value
                    : 'To Date',
              ),
           

  Future<void> _selectFromDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,          
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    // DateTime dateTime = selectedDate ?? DateTime.now();
    if (selectedDate != null) {
      String formattedDate =
          "${selectedDate.year}-${selectedDate.month}-${selectedDate.day}";
      // Set the formatted date to filteringController
      filteringController.setSelectedFromDate(formattedDate);
      print('from date $formattedDate');
    }
  }
  Future<void> _selectToDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
 if (selectedDate != null) {String formattedDate =       
"${selectedDate.year}-${selectedDate.month}-${selectedDate.day}";
filteringController.setSelectedToDate(formattedDate);
}

  }

}

And in my firestore i have collection of transactions where in each doc i have date field from which i am filtering data


Can you reproduce the problem with hardcoded values in the query rather than filteringController.selectedFromDate.value and filteringController.selectedToDate.value? If so, please update your question to show that. And then also add a screenshot from the Firestore console of a document that you expect to be returned.

Also: the code you shared doesn't seem to be using filteredQuery anywhere. Please consider how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example as that'll greatly improve the chances that someone can help.

I am usign filteredQuery in streambuilder like:
stream: filteredQuery.snapshot();

The date field value in that screenshot looks suspicious, hence my other request: to reproduce the problem with hard-coded values. If you can do that, edit your question to show just the code that queries the database, and maybe prints the results.
